# Missing formula fields when using force:recordEdit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, page-layout, force-recordedit

So I have some formula fields on my object page layout and it's not showing when I'm displaying it using force:recordEdit. Any ideia why it wouldn't show? I've checked the permissions and everything looks great...

Comment: Formula fields are not editable and those will not appear on the edit layout. They do not appear on classic edit ui either

Comment: Thanks for your message. But I'm not sure. For if you are on lightning and have a formula field on edit mode it will show up. :)

Comment: Ahh, I see that it seems to have been delivered in Spring 16'

Comment: Yeah, but it is not working when using force:recordEdit :/